# Contains Duplicate why this code Stack-Overflow?

Tags: java, stack-overflow

Here is the problem:

> Given an array of integers, find if the array contains any duplicates. Your function should return true if any value appears at least twice in the array, and it should return false if every element is distinct.

Here is my code, but there is an error for stack-overflow:

```
public static class Solution {
    public boolean containsDuplicate(int[] nums) {
        if (nums.length < 1)
            return false;
        return recursion(nums, 0, nums.length - 1);
    }

    private static boolean recursion(int[] nums, int start, int end) {
        if ((end - start) == 0) {
            return true;

        }

        if ((end - start) == 1) {
            if (nums[start] == nums[end]) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }
        boolean first = recursion(nums, start, (end - start) / 2 - 1);
        boolean second = recursion(nums, (end - start) / 2, end);

        if (first == false || second == false) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Debugger is your friend.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you can't work out what's going on by inspection, the next step should either be using a debugger or adding logging (or both). I'd start off by making `recursion` log the start and end every time it's called... that should help you find otu what's going wrong

Comment: that's a lot of work for something simple. why not just "unique" the array, and see if its length changes? That's all of about 2 lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

You could instead create a `HashSet` and check is the key has exists before

```
public boolean containsDuplicate(final int[] nums)
{
  Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
  for (int i : nums) {
    if (set.contains(i)) return true;
    set.add(i);
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: There are many ways to find if the array contains duplicates or not. The question that is asked is regarding why stack over flow error came using recursion. Your solution does not provide the required answer.

Answer (score 1):

This line: boolean second = recursion(nums, (end - start)/2, end);

especially this: (end - start)/2

Example:

with start = 0
end = 3

1. (3 - 0) / 2 = 1
2. (3 - 1) / 2 = 1
3. ...

Start will be always the same.

The same behavior appears with the first recursion, except start will be blocked at 0.

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced your error by running your code on my side - the problem is that  `recursion(nums, start, (end - start)/2 - 1)` gets to a point where start index = `2` and the end index is `-3` - the recursion therefore never stops.

Here is the correction - I tested it against an array like this:
`int[] nums = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5,6,6};`

```
private static boolean recursion(int[] nums, int start, int end) {

        if((end - start) == 0){ return false;}

        if((end - start) == 1){             
            //This is really where the recursion should end...unless if there were no duplicate, in which case we repeat
            if(nums[start] == nums[end]){
                return true;
            }
            else{
                //we checked all against the first number - now we move the start to the next item on list
                //so our new START is (start+1) and our new END (length-1)
                return recursion(nums, (start+1), (nums.length-1));
            }
        }
        else{
            if(end < 0){return false;}

            //here you evaluate if the start and end numbers are different 
            if(nums[start] == nums[end]){return true;}          
            return recursion(nums, start, (end - 1));          
        }       

    }
```

Please replace your "recursion" function with the code above and let's see if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

**BruteForce Approach:**

Steps:

> - You can take outer loop to iterate thorough the nums array till the length-1
> - Inner loop can be start from the i+1 and till the nums.length
> - At each iteration we can compare both the values of
>     nums[i] and nums[j]
> - If both the values are equals then we can return true else return false
> - As it's the brute force approach, it take O(n^2) time complexity.

```
class Solution {
    public boolean containsDuplicate(int[] nums) {
        for(int i = 0; i<nums.length-1; i++){
            for(int j = i+1; j<nums.length; j++){
                if(nums[i] == nums[j]){
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    bool containsDuplicate(vector<int>& nums) {
    unordered_map<int,int>m;
    for(int i = 0; i<nums.size(); i++){
        if(m.count(nums[i]) > 0){
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            m[nums[i]] = i;
        }
            
    }
    return false;
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A more neat solution is

```
class Solution {
    public boolean containsDuplicate(int[] nums) {
       Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
        for(int x:nums)
        {
            set.add(x);
        }
        if(set.size()==nums.length)return false;
        return true;
    }
```

}